# Running .NET 8 Web project also starts old project in IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, iis-express, .net-8.0

I have a .NET 8 Web project and an old ASP.NET web forms website in the same solution. When I run the .NET 8 project, it works fine but also starts IIS running the web forms website.

1. The new site was originally created to reverse proxy to the old app
2. There is only 1 startup project, the new app and it has no dependencies.
3. The old app is already running locally on IIS and I do
   not need a second instance started with IIS Express.
4. This even happens with a completely stand alone, new, clean web app project - seemingly just because there is a webforms web site in the solution.

I only want to run the .NET 8 project and IIS Express shouldn't start at all, how do I turn this off?

Comment: "This even happens with a completely stand alone, new, clean web app project - seemingly just because there is a webforms web site in the project" is interesting. Because VS2022 no longer enables IIS Express for newly created .NET 8 projects, I wonder how you got IIS Express into the picture. Please edit the question to include more details so that others might be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hmm yes I'm wondering too... IIS Express is set up to be the run configuration for the web site. To reproduce I would think you only need to create an old web forms web site (will likely need an older version of visual studio) and then create a new .net 8 web app in the same solution and try to run that independently

Comment: I did first create an old WebForms project and then add to the same solution a .NET 8 MVC web app. However, I cannot reproduce this issue. Like I said by default the .NET 8 project uses Kestrel, not IIS Express, so when debugging there isn't any IIS Express process spin out. There must be something else you neglect, and if you cannot share more details this question cannot be investigated further.

Comment: Did you try creating the .NET 8 web app by using the dotnet upgrade tool on the web forms project?

Comment: Right-click on your solution in Visual Studio and select "Properties" from the context menu. In the Solution Property Pages, navigate to the "Startup Project" section and choose the "Multiple startup projects" option. For the old ASP.NET Web Forms website, set the "Action" to "None." For the .NET 8 project, set the "Action" to "Start."

Answer (score 0):

> You mentioned "The new site was originally created to reverse proxy to the old app" but didn't say that .NET Upgrade Assistant was used, which hid the most important piece of information.

When you use .NET Upgrade Assistant to generate a .NET 8 project for your legacy WebForms project, there are several changes in your solution/project files to enable that migration,

1. VS2022 configured both projects as startup ones so that they can be launched together.
2. Profiles in the .NET 8 project `launchSettings.json` file are updated with `"ProxyTo": "http://localhost:xxxx"`, where the port number points to the WebForms project on IIS Express.

Debugging the solution at this moment should launch your WebForms app on IIS Express if that's the project setting. But again the .NET 8 web project should start on its own by default, not IIS Express.

You can force the WebForms project to run on IIS instead of IIS Express if you

1. Change its "Servers" setting under "Web" tag to "Local IIS".
2. Go back to .NET 8 project's `launchSettings.json` and modify `ProxyTo` to point to the right URL on IIS.

Then when you start debugging the solution, you will see in VS "Output" panel that the "Debug" channel shows information about both `w3wp.exe` and your .NET 8 executable. No IIS Express process will spin out.

Comment: I don't want Visual Studio to have the WebForms project running on Local IIS - thats already set up completely independently - I don't want the WebForms project to run at all

Comment: The question isn't how to get Visual Studio to run on IIS locally rather than express. It is already all set up on IIS and I don't want Visual Studio to tamper with it or try to run it at all. The .NET 8 project is set as the startup project - and I ONLY want that executable to run

Comment: @Moffen if you set the .NET 8 project as the only startup project, I wonder what exactly happened on your machine. But on mine I can only see VS2022 launches the .NET 8 executable and nothing more. Without accessing your machine, I don't think anyone here can dig further for you (but I have revealed all relevant technical details).

Comment: After deleting my .vs directory and restarting my computer... it appears to have resolved. I think it was in some way caching something like "VS2022 configured both projects as startup one"

Answer (score -1):

The .net proxy needs to run IIS for the legacy code to run and work. If you wanting to use the webforms WHILE you convert everything, then you quite much need to have IIS running. Only when all of the webforms are removed and gone can you turn off IIS.

So, while "kestrel" and the .net core runs as a proxy for those legacy web pages? You need IIS to run such pages, and the .net core can't run those .net framework pages designed around and dependent on IIS.

So, those web pages still need IIS to run and function correctly. Remove all the .net framework pages and then you can turn off IIS.

If .net core could run + consume asp.net webforms, then you would not need to convert to run webforms on .net core, but you do!

Webforms have boatloads of dependencies on windows, and IIS. You as a general rule need IIS to run + consume those webforms.

If you not using nor running any webforms? Then I suggest starting a whole new project in .net core, and then convert each page by hand into the new framework.

As noted, there is no automated conversion of webforms to MVC and .net core, and hence the migration tools simple setup a proxy in front of IIS to allow continued use of the legacy webforms in that .net core project. Thus, the idea over time is you then convert the webforms to MVC pages one by one.

Even without .net core, conversion of webforms to MVC is a 100% re-write anyway. Going from MVC .net framework to .net core? Often very few changes, but from webforms to MVC, (.net framework or .net core) is a differing matter. So, going from webforms is a complete rewrite of the webforms application, and such work is done by hand, and no automated tools exist for such a conversion.

So, yes, you will need the correct .net framework(s) (not core) installed on the server, and you also need IIS up and running to process those webform pages.

If your new .net core application does not have any dependences or does not use any of the webforms? Then remove the webforms project, or better yet, create a brand new .net core project, and import all of the existing .net core code and views etc.  In other words, either you need the webforms in that project (to run from the one same site), or you do not. This is quite much a 0 or 1 choice here.

If you do not want or need any IIS stuff in your project, then create a project without any .net framework code or web forms in it.

Comment: I DO have the old code running - just in another implementation (but good suggestion, I updated my question). Also there will be many times I just want to run the new code without proxying to the new code so how start the app independently

Comment: Well, then remove the .net webforms from that project.  There not really much of a "in between choice here that I am aware of". Until such time all of the web forms stuff is not included in the project, then I can't really see how else this can work. I mean, if you don't want any IIS stuff to run or start, then remove all that stuff. If you need to run without IIS, then I don't see how that's going to be possible unless all .net framework and the web forms are removed from the project.

Comment: That's the thing... the .NET 8 projects don't mention the webforms web site (as far as I can see) and so there are no references for me to remove from them - IIS Express just keeps magically starting when I try to start the .NET 8 projects